# why is my runnable giving ANR?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a `SurfaceView`, calling its `onDraw()` method from a `Thread`, based on [this tutorial](http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/).  My app is giving ANR after I start the below code running.

I have tried [implementing Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread/541506#541506), instead of extending `Thread` but it still gives ANR.

As far as I know [there's nothing else running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212459/why-this-handler-runnable-is-slowing-down-my-app-if-it-is-launched-on-a-service/6212531#6212531) on the app when the ANR occurs.   (The ANRs only started occurring when I added this code:)

```
package com.thunderrabbit.run;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends Thread {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    // desired fps
    private final static int    MAX_FPS = 50;
    // maximum number of frames to be skipped
    private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
    // the frame period
    private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;  

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private PageGLSurfaceView gamePanel;
    private boolean running;    // flag to hold game state
    private Canvas canvas;

    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MySurfaceView gamePanel) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sleepTime = 0;
        while(running)
        {
            canvas = null;
            try
            {
                synchronized (surfaceHolder)
                {
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    // resetting the frames skipped
                    framesSkipped = 0;
                    // update game state
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    // render state to the screen
                    // draws the canvas on the panel
                    this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
                    // calculate how long did the cycle take
                    timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                    // calculate sleep time
                    sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                    if (sleepTime > 0) {
                        // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                        try {
                            // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                            // very useful for battery saving
                            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }

                    while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                        // we need to catch up
                        // update without rendering
                        this.gamePanel.update();
                        // add frame period to check if in next frame
                        sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
                        framesSkipped++;
                    }
                    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    gamePanel.onDraw(canvas);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            // update game state
            // render state to the screen
        }
        DebugLog.d(TAG, "Game loop executed ");
    }
}
```

What's causing the ANR?  Should I implement `Runnable` or extend `Thread` in a significantly different way?

Comment: If the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.
Do you know about "Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)"? I think this will be your solution.

Comment: @Balaji I have seen runOnUiThread, but forgot about it in this case.  Also, sorry I wasn't able to post the LogCat output; I basically got it solved before causing the problem again.  :-)

Comment: So, how did the selected answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gamePanel` extends from `SurfaceView` and receives your input (through `onTouchEvent()`). In other words, its your UI thread. When you are calling `gamePanel.onDraw(canvas)` It is blocking (waiting for hardware to draw on the `canvas`) and so you get ANR.

The `MainThread` seems to be the rendering thread (seeing as how it owns the `canvas`), and it should be the only one rendering. Your game logic should go in the `MainGamePanel` or in a separate thread altogether.

So ideally I would have three threads:

- one for input (the main activity which spends most of its time doing nothing)
- one for game logic (a separate thread which is updated all the time)
- one for drawing (which owns the canvas and is drawing all the time)

Comment: I'm having the same problem but my UI thread is not the gamePanel I'm using an xml layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128232/surfaceview-disappear-onresume

Answer (score 1):

Using `Thread.sleep(...)` blocks the thread.  If you block on the UI thread, your app is essentially frozen and the OS will consider it to be non-responsive.  Instead, you should look into using Timer.  Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android/3039718#3039718) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java/1453321#1453321).

Basically instead of sleeping your thread until it's next execution, you set a timer so you can be called when it's time to execute again.